# What is the purpose of this Promise wrapper in producer-consumer queue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, es6-promise, producer-consumer

I am reading [Node.js Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1839214112) and am trying to understand the following example of a producer-consumer pattern in implementing limited parallel execution (my questions in comments):

```js
export class TaskQueuePC extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(concurrency) {
    super();
    this.taskQueue = [];
    this.consumerQueue = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < concurrency; i++) {
      this.consumer();
    }
  }

  async consumer() {
    while (true) {
      try {
        const task = await this.getNextTask();
        await task();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }

  async getNextTask() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      if (this.taskQueue.length !== 0) {
        return resolve(this.taskQueue.shift());
      }

      this.consumerQueue.push(resolve);
    });
  }

  runTask(task) {
    // why are we returning a promise here?
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // why are we wrapping our task here?
      const taskWrapper = () => {
        const taskPromise = task();
        taskPromise.then(resolve, reject);
        return taskPromise;
      };

      if (this.consumerQueue.length !== 0) {
        const consumer = this.consumerQueue.shift();
        consumer(taskWrapper);
      } else {
        this.taskQueue.push(taskWrapper);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

1. In the constructor, we create queues for both tasks and consumers, and then execute the `consumer` method up to the concurrency limit.
2. This pauses each `consumer` on `const task = await getNextTask()` which returns a pending promise.
3. Because there are no tasks yet in our task queue, the resolver for the promise is pushed to the consumer queue.
4. When a task is added with `runTask`, the consumer (the pending promise's resolver) is plucked off the queue and called with the task. This returns execution to the `consumer` method, which will run the `task()`, eventually looping again to await another task or sit in the queue.

What I cannot grok is the purpose of the Promise and `taskWrapper` in the `runTask` method. It seems we would have the same behavior if both the Promise and `taskWrapper` were omitted:

```js
  runTask(task) {
    if (this.consumerQueue.length !== 0) {
      const consumer = this.consumerQueue.shift();
      consumer(task);
    } else {
      this.taskQueue.push(task);
    }
  }
```

In fact, when I execute this version I get the same results. Am I missing something?

Comment: "*why are we returning a promise here?*" - so that the caller of `runTask` can wait until their task has been executed!

Comment: You haven't shown how you construct the `TaskQueuePC` and how you are calling `runTask`

Answer (score 0):

Verbatim

> we create a taskWrapper function (1) that, when executed, has the responsibility for running the input task and forwarding the status of the Promise returned by task() to the outer Promise returned by runTask().

So in order to return a promise and forward the callbacks you need the task wrapper, and that is the intention of the author. Alternatively if `runTask` is defined to NOT return a promise like in your shorter version, you can then use it like #2 below. IMO #1 is more straighforward to use if you need to do something with the task output.

```js
const queue = new TaskQueuePC(concurrency)
const task = () => { return Promise.resolve("task done") }
const onTaskDone = (status) => { console.log(`Status: ${status}` }
 
// 1. if runTask implementation returns a promise.
queue.runTask(task).then(onTaskDone)

// 2. When runTask doesn't need to return a promise.
const taskWrapper = async () => {
  const status = await task()
  onTaskDone(status)
}

queue.runTask(taskWrapper)
```